# nivo slider does work for only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, nivo-slider

My nivo slider runs only for one time at the time of loading very fastly then it wont loop again

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var j = jQuery.noConflict();
    j(document).ready(function () {
        j('#slider').nivoSlider();
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
      prevText: '',
      nextText: '',
      controlNav: true,
    });
});
</script>

    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/slider/img_1.jpg" alt="slide 1" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/slider/img_2.jpg" alt="slide 2" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/slider/img_3.jpg" alt="slide 3" /></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: <link href="~/Styles/Default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Styles/nivo-slider.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script>

Comment: just combine ur two scripts into one...

Comment: because you right the function inside the $(window).load() wirte it in document ready or anything

Comment: see console bug ... I think you have some bug which stops the working process

Comment: please help me i m struck here for last two days tried every thing available but nothing works

Comment: it is strucking on last image

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the trailing comma after `controlNav: true` - this is likely breaking something.

Comment: Can you post a link to a live version? That would make it easier to narrow it down.